# Cannot read properties of undefined on vue js unit test

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a problem with a unit test made with vue test utils and jest

This is the function i want to test :

```
async getConfig() {
            try {
                const response = await getConfig()
                console.log(response.data)
                if (response.data) {
                    store.commit('common/setConfiguration', response.data)
                }
            } catch (err) {
                this.$notify({
                    group: 'alert', type: 'error', title: err.response.data.error, text: err.response.data.message, duration: -1
                })
            }
        },
```

This is my test :

```
it('getConfig - should commit the configuration when getConfig is successful', async () => {
        const response = {
            REDIRECT_URI: 'test',
            CLIENT_ID: '259'
        }
        const spy = vi.spyOn(store, 'commit')
        component.mock.onGet('myURL').reply(200, response)
        await component.getConfig()
        await flushPromises()
        expect(component.mock.history.get.length).toBe(1)
        expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledWith('common/setConfiguration', response)
    })
```

I'm facing this error :
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'data')
I'm trying to resolve that problem since this morning but i'm not able to understand
The console.log in my function shows me the good result, as expected the 'reponse' object declared in my test but i'v got this error
I can give you more context if necessarly. Thank you